# Question about notation, language, and meaning in the context of combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, functions, graphing-functions

In my math class today, my teacher defined a function as follows:

A string on alphabet $[m]$ of length $n$ is a function:

$$
s: [n] \rightarrow [m]
$$

To seque back to math from programming, what exactly is this function?  It reads like it is taking an $n$-length input and outputting an $m$-length output.

I think some other specifications might be necessary: for instance, that the function is 1:1: for a number, $n$, there is one output, $s_n$.

Is this specification implied in the arrow notation?  Or is it missing, where the arrow notation could just as easily imply that $s$ in fact, takes the whole of $[n]$ and produces a vector of length $[m]$...and I should fill in the gaps...

Also, in terms of programming, a string can be defined as the physical sequence *after* the mapping occurs...

Finally (and here is where all of my trouble stems from), the intent of this definition is that $s$ produce a tuple, or indexed item (indexed by $n$)...but the function signature indicates that it produces a $[m]$...

Honestly, I hate it when I wind up answering myself by rewriting the question.

---

---

$$
\begin{align}
f(n) &= x, x \text{ is a valid index of m}\\
s(n) &= (m_{f(n)})_n\\
s(1) &= (m_{f(1)})_1\\
\end{align}
$$

Where the tuple of information, $(n,m)$ is baked into the ordered list, $[m]$.

It's funny, but I have no idea why I was confused anymore...

Anyhow, the rule I've got is that with $s: [n] \rightarrow [m]$, 1:1ness is implied by default...for every 1 $n$, there is a single index number from $m$ placed next to $n$ by virtue of it being output in order with $n$...so the type signature of the output is actually the map, $\lbrace \lbrace 1,f(1) \rbrace, ... \rbrace$...

Comment: Yes...the actual notation she used was $s:[n] \rightarrow [m]$...but I would typically use your notation for a sequence.  Sequence is her intent here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: How so? because then the alphabet and the string are the exact same thing??

Comment: This question sounds *very* disturbing to me, to say the least. Does it have to do with the fact that even relatively modern programming languages (like the one used in Mathematica) use  a blunt equality sign for assigning values, so that we see equations of the form $k=k+1$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  When you use Mathematica, and you set $k=k+1$, there are millions of lines of code under the hood, compiling that statement into a set of instructions for the processor.  At some point, you function turns into the abstract equivalent of a ticker-tape, with the processor being the machine that looks at it.  
$$$$
At the intermediate stage, the equals sign--and every character in your equation, becomes a function.  The memory signature of your function has a complexity of the bit size of "k", depending on your numerical type, and the bit size of "1".

Comment: @Christian Blatter ...wherein the equals sign is actually something much different than simply 'equals', and is a very context-specific function.  For instance, in your case, it is a token indicating to the compiler that it should inspect the line for a function (in this case a recursion), and build a set of instructions accordingly.  

$$$$
That means that the equals sign is actually a "function" in a very real sense--a sense that our brains hide discretely under the hood (just like depth perception, facial recognition, and color discrimination, for instance)--and once you program for a while

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  ...it becomes apparent that steps are often missing in math formalism.  Nonetheless, it seems to me that, in this particular case, the function defined is a double function: 1) it matches an association of the input $n$ and the corresponding alphabet $m$...and 2) it outputs the letter of the alphabet associated with $n$, such that $s(n_0) = x$, where $x \in [m]$. 

$$$$

Since this is trying to define the function, I am wondering where to place the second function, and I'm settling on the '$=$' sign, because there doesn't seem to be anywhere else to place it...

Comment: @ChristianBlatter as far as mathematica goes though,  *even the numbers are functions*, because (presumably) it does not evaluate the number until the last possible second, whereupon it figures out how 'big' the number is, in terms of memory, and chooses the correct numerical type to output. 

$$$$

Mathematica is a special language though, and not something I know much about.  It is interpreted, so it should have lower performance than compiled languages at problems of high (computational) complexity...but it seems to break the rules in some respects...

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  ...Regardless, they probably accomplish most of it by functionalizing everything (i.e., employing lambda calculus), then chaining functions and doing lazy evaluation; and also spending the $$$ on leveraging architecture.  It's like a 2 gig install, so its possible they also hard coded a lot of performance--my ex boss did that to get around a bottle neck in a missile warning receiver's calculation ability...he just calculated a terabyte of adjacency matrices or something to hard code all the visual processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of $[n]$ are naturally ordered, and this order gives a sequence $[s_{1}, \ldots, s_{n}]$, where each of the $s_{i} \in [m]$.  In other words, you have $n$ symbols from $[m]$ laid out in a specified order.

It is sometimes convenient to think of this functionally, so the $i$th character of the string is given by $s(i) = s_{i}$. As a programmer, you can think of this as like an access function, to read a specified character from your string. You have that $[n]$ is the domain of the function (the positions that can be read), and $[m]$ is the codomain (the characters that might be in those positions).

Note that you are thinking of your "alphabet" as the numbers $1, \ldots, m$, because you really don't care what the symbols actually *are*, from a mathematical point of view, only how *many* symbols you are using.

Comment: Ok, so it is kindof a combo function.  So when a math person says, $s:[n]\rightarrow [m]$, they aren't saying the function $s$ is returning an $m$ length sequence modified by the interior function of $n$, but rather an $[n]$ sized sequence comprised of $elements \in [m]$...

Comment: So the output is constant across the tokens $[]$ and the type changes across $n$ and $m$?  It just seems like the definition should be: $s:[n] \rightarrow [x_1,...,x_n]$ where $x_n: n \rightarrow [m]$...haha, nevermind, I think I'm starting to get the implicit stuff--just used it there.  The first term implies the dimension of the output in the mapping notation!  That's the implicit rule I was looking for...

Answer (score 3):

A *string* of length $n$ is a finite sequence $s_1\cdots s_n$ with $s_i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ for each $i$. Writing $s(i)=s_i$ you get a map $s\colon\{1,\ldots,s\}\to\{1,\ldots,m\}$.

Comment: This statement seems correct to me.  This is a definition of the mapping function.  I would accept it...except it isn't really settling the confusion of the definition above.  

$$$$

In other words, if the teacher said what you've just said, I would have been all over it...But she has introduced a lot of idiomatic math here, and I need to break it down, so the next time she uses it, I won't have trouble.

Comment: I regret that I don't understand what you mean. A string is simply a function from a finite set to the alphabet, so I see no way of understand "it is obviously at least 2". We are always talking about univalent functions, the values at each point of the domain are not functions. PS: I was referring to what you erased.

Comment: not sure what the last comment is in response to...but I have absolutely no problem with your definition...I just need to figure out how "a string applied on alphabet $[m]$" with function $s: [n]  \rightarrow  [m]$ could possibly give rise to anything other than the alphabet itself, $[m]$...since that is the definition of $s$.  In other words,  either the definition is wrong, as written,or 

$$
s: [n] \rightarrow [m]
$$

Is just implicitly $[s_1,...,s_n], \forall s, s \in [m]$...but I'm thinking, this just isn't right.  This is math. The symbols should work out.  My mind is like, that is not..

Comment: ... something that should be, or is allowed to be inferred...

Answer (score 1):

Review your programming. A string of length $n$ can be represented as a function eating an input $i \in [n]$ and spitting out a single alphabet letter. For example, the string `Hello` can be represented using the following function (in pseudocode):

```
function hello(i):
  if i = 1 then return 'H'
  if i = 2 then return 'e'
  if i = 3 then return 'l'
  if i = 4 then return 'l'
  if i = 5 then return 'o'
```

The type of this function is exactly $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \to A$, where $A$ is any set containing all the letters in Hello.

Comment: Hmm, seems you are doing the same thing the math teacher is doing.  

You have actually defined a triple function.  You have an alphabet, $\lbrace a,b,c,... \rbrace$, an input sequence, and an output string.

Comment: You've just rewrapped it in syntactical sugar, but there are still three fundamental units.

Comment: And you are making the same mistake. I suggest you review your course material on functional programming.

Comment: @bordeo, so you are claiming that function takes 3 parameters? I disagree strongly but maybe this is semantics.

Comment: @JB King  You've hard-coded your third parameter.  The alphabet is an input.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus  I don't have functional programming course material; if you can add to it, I will add to the question.   Because, frankly, two functions are what I've got--n onto m, defining intermediate functions as the abstract concept "mapping", and then the final state of that function onto the string $s$, defining the second stage as the abstract concept "output", so that you have $f(n,m)\rightarrow  string$

Comment: @JB King, even if the alphabet is in your head, it is still there.  So your function is:

$$
f(i,alphabet) \rightarrow 'hello'
$$

so that the only information that the function $f$ is responsible for is the mapping from $n$ onto the alphabet, $m$, to produce the string...and nothing else.  That is the string function...and the operation it employs is the concept called "mapping", right?  Is that a definition we can stand behind?

Comment: Is the alphabet actually part of the function or part of the overall context? If I add extra stuff to the alphabet, does that change the function? Should it?

Comment: @bordeo,@JBKing Please have this discussion somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some concrete examples would be helpful. To run the code in this answer, you'll need to install the [tensor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tensor) package for [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/).

---

Let's say my friend is moving to Florida, and they want to give me their phone number so we can stay in touch. What exactly do they need to give me?

To call my friend, all I need is a way to get the digits of my friend's phone number, one by one, so I can punch them into my phone. Accordingly, my friend gives me the following Haskell function.

```
import Data.Ordinal

genDigit :: Ten -> Nine
genDigit First = toOrdinal 2
genDigit (Succ First) = toOrdinal 3
genDigit (Succ (Succ First)) = toOrdinal 9
genDigit i = toOrdinal (p - q + r)
  where p = fromOrdinal (genDigit (toOrdinal ((fromOrdinal i) - 1)))
        q = fromOrdinal (genDigit (toOrdinal ((fromOrdinal i) - 2)))
        r = fromOrdinal (genDigit (toOrdinal ((fromOrdinal i) - 3)))`
```

When I want to call my friend, I call `genDigit (toOrdinal 1)` and punch the result into my phone. Then I call `genDigit (toOrdinal 2)` and punch that in. I keep punching in digits all the way up to `genDigit (toOrdinal 10)`. Then, the phone connects me to my friend.

---

This is, admittedly, a really weird way to give someone a phone number. When your friend wants to give you their phone number, they probably give you a static memory device, like a piece of paper, with all the digits of the phone number written on it. In other words, when your friend wants to give you their phone number, you probably expect them to give you something like this:

```
digits = [2, 3, 9, 8, 2, 3, 9, 8, 2, 3]
```

I think this is what you mean when you say that "on a computer, a simple map, $s \colon [n] \rightarrow [m]$ is not a string until you allocate memory, evaluate the map and output the results of the mapping into the memory." When you ask your friend for their phone number, you expect to get a static block of memory, so you've decided that a phone number *is* a static block of memory.

To understand your teacher's way of speaking, I suggest you think in a different way: think of a phone number as **a way to get digits to punch into your phone**. From this point of view, you can't use the list `digits` as a phone number until you have a function to access it.

```
memDigit :: Ten -> Nine
memDigit i = toOrdinal (digits!!(fromOrdinal i - 1))
```

The function `memDigit` is the phone number; the list `digits` is just a resource used in defining the function. It's not hard to check that `genDigit` and `memDigit` give you the same output if you give them the same input. In other words, the Haskell functions `genDigit` and `memDigit` are two different expressions of the same abstract function $d \colon [10] \rightarrow [9]$.

---

As support for the point of view I'm suggesting, notice that when I use `genDigit` to contact my friend, the digits I'm dialing are never all written down in memory at the same time. In other words, I can use the function $d \colon [10] \rightarrow [9]$ to call my friend even if I never "allocate memory, evaluate the map and output the results of the mapping into the memory." To me, this is a pretty compelling reason to call the function $d$ a phone number even if I never write all its outputs down in one place.

A more practical argument for the "phone numbers as functions" point of view is that it generalizes nicely to situations where phone numbers are infinitely long—maybe my phone number is the [infinite Fibonacci string](http://blog.zacharyabel.com/2012/05/the-fibonacciest-string/), and yours is the [Kolakoski sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence). I can't give you my phone number by writing it down on a piece of paper, but I can give it to you as a Haskell function `fibDigit`:

```
fibDigit :: Int -> Nine
fibDigit i = fibRecurse i [toOrdinal 1, toOrdinal 8] [toOrdinal 1]

fibRecurse :: Int -> [Nine] -> [Nine] -> Nine
fibRecurse i oneBack twoBack =
  if i <= length oneBack
    then oneBack!!(i - 1)
    else fibRecurse i (oneBack ++ twoBack) oneBack
```

When I call this a practical argument, I'm not joking. Haskell actually handles infinite lists by thinking of them as functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to the appropriate alphabet.

Comment: Thanks man...That makes sense--especially the last part.  For some reason, this definition put my mind in a time-warp.  Would you say that this is true: 

$$
\begin{align}
string &= \lbrace 6,5,4,3 \rbrace\\
s&:[n] \rightarrow [m]\\
[n] &= \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace\\
[m] &= \lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace\\
s(n_0) &= 6\\
s(n_1) &= 5\\
\end{align}
$$

And this is false:

$$
s(n_0) = \lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,\lbrace1,6\rbrace \rbrace
$$

Where, in the latter case, the result is a "map of $n_0$ onto alphabet $[m]$, with $s:[n] \rightarrow [m]$," as I read it...

Comment: @bordeo: I *think* you've got the right idea in the first thing you wrote, but it's hard for me to tell because your notation is a little non-standard. For convenience, let's use the symbols $A$ and $B$ in place of $[4]$ and $[6]$. When a mathematician writes $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, they basically mean "$A$ is a data type with possible values $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$." You could write this in Haskell as `data A = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4`. The mathematician's $s \colon A \to B$ is Haskell's `s :: A -> B`.

Comment: @bordeo: You should now see that a mathematician would be confused by the assertion $s(n_0) = 6$, just as a Haskell compiler would be confused by the assertion `s n_0 = 6`,  because $n_0$ isn't a possible value of the type $A$ (and in fact you haven't even defined it anywhere). You should write $s(1) = 6$ instead, or `s 1 = 6` in Haskell.

Comment: @bordeo: Finally, you've described $\text{string}$ as a data type with possible values 6, 5, 4, and 3, but I don't think that's what you intend. You want $\text{string}$ to be a sequence. A mathematician would typically write that as $\text{string} = (6, 5, 4, 3)$; in Haskell, you'd write `string = [6, 5, 4, 3]`.

Comment: As an exercise, try writing out a full definition of the data types $A$ and $B$ and the function $s$ in Haskell. You can check your work by loading the function into GHCI and evaluating it. (I've belatedly realized that `data A = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4` won't compile, because `1` isn't a valid name for a value constructor. You can work around this by naming the values `I`, `II`, `III` and `IV` instead.)

Comment: Thanks man.  I have the idea--And I've used "map" dozens of times in F#...and I do it all the time in Python, conceptually...but I just don't have a handle on how they do sequences, typing--and basically all the areas that you've sort of hit on--in math notation.  That's the hard part about this question:  if I could ask it clearly, I wouldn't have a question, if that makes sense...

$$
$$

Anyhow, my intent was to frame a string as an ordered sequence...$[n]$ as the sequence from 1 to n, and the map being an association of the position, 1 to n, with the corresponding $m$ value

Comment: So, to apply the suggestions:

$$
\begin{align}
string &= (6,5,4)\\
s &: \mathbf{n} \rightarrow \mathbf{m}\\
\mathbf{n} &= [1,2,3]\\
\mathbf{m} &= [1,2,3,4,5,6]\\
s(\mathbf{n}) &= string\\
s(n_0) &=6\\
\end{align}
$$

But then, in the actual definition:

$$
s:[n] \rightarrow [m]
$$

How have brackets changed things?  Also, it seems like the notation is indicating that $s$ outputs the whole alphabet vector, $m$, as versus an $m$-type vector of length $n$.  What is the language convection that allows me to interpret the definition of $s$ as the latter of the two cases as versus the former?

Comment: @bordeo: The symbol $[3]$ is just a common notation for the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$—that is, the type with possible values 1, 2, and 3. The symbol $\mathbf{3}$ can be used as well, and in fact I prefer it. I strongly encourage you to stop using the symbols $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{m}$ in your examples, and stick to concrete types like $\mathbf{3} = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $\mathbf{6} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Comment: @bordeo: With that said, what do you mean when you write $s(\mathbf{3})$? To me, this doesn't make any sense, because $\mathbf{3}$ is a type, not a value. What you wrote is like writing `abs Integer` in Haskell, which results in an interpreter error. (Mathematicians sometimes do use notation like the one you used, but it will not help resolve your confusion, so you shouldn't think about it right now.)

Comment: lol, literally, symbol for symbol, my math teacher wrote on the board:

$$
s:[n] \rightarrow [m]
$$

And she is a phd in math at Ga Tech (top five in US)...and it is consistent with the terminology in Donald Knuth's (phd, Stanford, really famous guy) Art of Programming (the definitive work in Combinatorics), from what I can remember...

So my notation isn't coming from left field. Maybe it is a country thing.  $s(n_0)$ means $s(1)$, not $s(type)$...this is the whole source of my consternation, since obviously you are having the exact same issue I am with the convert between programming...

Comment: ...and math. the type is apparently *wholly* specified by $[n]$, a vector or sequence from the $\mathbb{N}$ starting at 1 and ending at $n$...and "maps" $[n]$ to positions in $[m]$; it pairs the indexes listed in $[1,...,n] = [n]$ with positions in $[m] = [1,...,m]$ to output $[s] = [m_1,...,m_n]$, where $s(1) = m_1$, etc.  

$$
$$

The confusing part is that, in a regular "map" in programming, there are three elements:  the input list/sequence, the alphabet list/sequence, and the output list/sequence.   The function that is just the input list/sequence applied to the alphabet is *not* the map

Comment: ...in functional languages, it is the "unevaluated map", the "to be calculated" (in the lazy paradigm).  

$$
$$

Anyhow, that is why I said the things I said in my earlier edits--I'm trying to bridge the gap between the two notations which are each obviously true and trivial...but which are clearly at odds with each other in a really subtle and irritating way.

Comment: ...It doesn't really matter.  It just means that there are linguistic limitations to the notation: it isn't clear what the scope of the map is.  For instance, are:

$$
s: n \rightarrow [m]\\
s: n \rightarrow m\\
s:[n] \rightarrow [m]\\
s:[n] \rightarrow m\\
$$

All maps? (where $[m]$ is interpreted as the vector or sequence).

Comment: And if all those are maps...then s is really just the definition of a function given an integer input, in which everything maps to the number line...It just seems like a tautology...it isn't constrained at all...and assumes that the function returns something.  For instance, I could satisfy the definition of the map with a function that returns nothing--a null function.  So the math notation is making some assumptions about the reader's knowledge of how math things are done...

Comment: For instance, in code, a function that satisfies the map definition (to the letter of the map definition: it takes an $n$, goes and looks at the corresponding position in $m$, and stops) need not return anything, so how could it be analytically the same as another function that satisfies the map definition by returning a string?

Comment: @bordeo: I think I see some of the sources of your confusion. First, the line $s \colon [3] \to [6]$ is not a function definition. It's what a C++ programmer would call a function prototype, and what a Haskell programmer would call a function type signature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34573/discussion-between-vectornaut-and-bordeo).